# Convergence in moments implies weak distribution in a special case?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, weak-convergence

I know this is definitely not true in general. Consider this special case: $(X_n, X)$ are all random variables that map to $[0,1]$ that is a bounded interval. Given that $$\lim_{n\to +\infty}E[X_n^k] = E[X^k]$$ for all $k\in\mathbb{Z}^+$ (i.e. every moment converges). It seems to me that the following is true $$X_n \Rightarrow^d X$$ (i.e. weak convergence), but I have no idea on how to start. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a direct elementary proof. Let $f \in C[0,1]$. Given $\epsilon>0$, the Weierstrass approximation theorem ensures that there is a polynomial $g$ such that $\displaystyle \max_{x \in [0,1]} |g(x)-f(x)| <\epsilon$.
Writing $g$ as a sum of monomials (and the hypothesis on moment convergence) imply that $Eg(X_n) \to Eg(X)$ as $n \to \infty.$
Therefore the triangle inequality yields
$$\limsup_n |E (f(X_n) -f(X))| \le 2\epsilon+ \limsup_n |E (g(X_n) -g(X))|=2\epsilon \,,$$
so the limsup on the LHS must equal $0$. This proves weak convergence.

Answer (score 0):

It is true but it requires a few theorems. First of all, any sequence of probability measures on a compact set is relatively compact. All weak limit points of $P\circ X_n^{-1}$ are the same because on $[0,1]$, moments determine the distribution uniquely. Combining these we get the result.